# What exactly does "co" in Intl.Collator() or localeCompare()?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-intl

As far as I see, `Intl.Collator()` and `localeCompare()` have `locales` argument. Mainly it helps to specify BCP 47 language tag, but also this property can indicate such parameters as `co`, `kn`, `kf`.

I've read in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/Collator#parameters) about `co` that...

> Variant collations for certain locales. Possible values include: "big5han", "dict", "direct", "ducet", "gb2312", "phonebk", "phonetic", "pinyin", "reformed", "searchjl", "stroke", "trad", "unihan". This option can be also be set through the options property "collation".

I don't understand what exactly `co` does. What does it collate? Maybe it concerns collating the locales when we specify one more language tag?

Comment: Please don't add tags just because they look the same as what you're asking about. Read the [tag info for `co`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/co/info) and you'll see it has nothing to do with collation. Same with [intl](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intl/info), which is about a PHP library.

Comment: If you really want to know the ins and outs of collation, the [Unicode Collation Algorithm](https://unicode.org/reports/tr10/) is where it's at. You'd also need to know about [Unicode Technical Standard #35](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-collation.html#Contents). Basically, it's a huge topic.